# NetworkManager quits randomly causing disruption to the internet connection

Tags: 10.10, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick, and I have this problem where the NetworkManager just quits randomly causing the internet connection to be broken. The only way to get it back is to log-off or restart the computer. This is very annoying as you have to close all the work you are doing and log-off or restart the computer.

The Networkmanager icon in the panel is not visible anymore when it quits as shown in the screenshot here.
[image]

However the hardware icon for the wireless is still on which shows that this is a software problem.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Is there a command or something to restart the networkmanager applet when it quits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for nm-applet is `nm-applet`. You could try that from command line. On a very different note may be you could try some alternative for network manager like [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I too have a lot of issues lately with Network Manager. It all started with bluetooth tethering dying, which led me to download a beta version, but that one had a major memory leak. however, that beta version also had the issue that the normal one did and that yours did.
I have not see any fix yet, but here is what i found out through someone else:

from command line type

```
killall nm-applet
```

then hit Alt-F2 and type

```
nm-applet
```

then hit ok.

The reason i can't do it from command line is because i can't use my command line window for anything also, although i am such a newbie, i am sure there is a way.

I hope this helps.

ps: restarting the network-manager service, doesn't fix the problem. but the above does.

Take care, and let's hope this gets fixed soon.